# How do I obtain battery stats on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, battery

I am looking for simple statistics like:

- the average battery life time
- or average screen on time
- relative power consumption of the different components (screen, wifi, system, applications)

ideally, for each power plan individually.

In summary, something similar to GSam Battery monitor but for windows, not android:
[image: screenshot GSam battery monitor for android]

Trivia: I have the impression that my laptop does not run as long on battery as the "4 hours and 3 minutes remaining" predicted when hovering the battery icon in the taskbar at full charge and want to diagnose the problem (at least confirm its existence objectively).

I tried to click on the battery icon in the task bar, but the desired information was not shown.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are describing in your post. Please take a few minutes to explain what the problem is, what you have done to try to resolve it and where you are stuck. Then ask a specific question. If you need help, read [ask] in the [help].

Comment: better? or worse?

Comment: Yes, much better. Have you looked Windows 10 Store? There are several there. Also, depending what brand of laptop you have, some manufacturers have utilities for this purpose.

Comment: Only one of the 37 apps that show up when searching for "battery" gives more information than the current battery charge state; and that is a time curse of the charge state. Also, if there was an app like GSam for windows then there must be some API calls or log files containing that information... I'd prefer directly using them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has such options in the settings app (`System -> Battery saver -> Battery use` / URI:`ms-settings:batterysaver-usagedetails`):

[image]

Only the time since last charge is missing, here I use [Battery Super Saver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/die-beste-batterie/9nblggh1z0w7)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this dialog! However, the app you mentioned is only available for windows phone, not on laptops.

Comment: hm, watch this video and try the commands to analyze the raw data from Windows 10: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-157-Energy-Estimation-Engine-E3 maybe this helps to see why your battery life is short

Comment: Awesome! In short: run `powercfg /srumutil` in an elevated promt and analyse the created `srumutil.csv` with, for example, Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to and to extend, what @magicandre1981 said,
windows' tool `powercfg` can be used to obtain detailed statistics:

- use `powercfg /srumutil` in an elevated promt and analyse the created `srumutil.csv` with, for example, Excel to obtain detailed statistics about wich application used how much energy by which device in which mode
- use `powercfg /batteryreport` in an elevated promt and view the created `battery-report.html` for most interestingly:

  - "Information about each currently installed battery"
  - "Battery drains over the last 3 days"
  - "Current estimate of battery life based on all observed drains since OS install"
- use `powercfg /energy` in an elevated promt, let windows analyze your configuration for a minute and view the created `energy-report.html` for potential power problems